# Set any range with userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently looking for a way to assign a range via UserForm. I've often encountered the example with the RefEdit, which unfortunately does not fit 100% to my problem.

Is there a way where the enduser can assigns a range with a textbox? The User should be asked in which column in his sheet the relevant numerical values are and on that basis, the macro should adjust the range.

For example: 
The user types the range is in column H and there for the macro adjust to:

```
ws.Range("H2: H" & lastrow)
```

Comment: Can't you just replace the "H" with whatever column letter the user types into the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ws.Range(Var & "2:" & Var & lastrow)
```